# Utility to push data into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, utility

I need to build a common utility for unix/Windows based system to push data into hadoop system. User can run that utility from any platform and should be able to push data into HDFS.

WebHDFS can be one of the option but curious to know if anything else available.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not to build an java hadoop client that connect to the hadoop namenode and write the data the user want using the hadoop-client api?

Comment: Yes Simone...Do you have list of jars that will be required to run Java code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually make a maven project and I add this dependency to my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then push data into HDFS it's very easy with the hadoop java api, this is a simple example just to see how it works:

```java
String namenodeLocation = "hdfs://[your-namenode-ip-address]:[hadoop:listening-port]/";

Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get( new URI( namenodeLocation ), configuration );
Path file = new Path(namenodeLocation+"/myWonderful.data");

FSDataOutputStream outStream = hdfs.create(file);

byte[] coolDataToPushToHDFS = new byte[1500];

outStream.write(coolDataToPushToHDFS);
outStream.close();

hdfs.close();
```

It's a really simple program. I think the steps you have to do are:

1. Let users choose the input/data to push
2. Use hadoop java api to send file/data to your cluster
3. Give some feedback to the user.

You can also append information to a file, not only create new file.

Give a look to the documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/

Comment: hadoop-client.jar is enough to run code? Or I need add more dependencies like log4j , slf4 etc?

Comment: it's enough for now. log4j, slf4 are others 3rd party library. If you use only the hadoop api you don't need these depencencies. Btw depends of what you want to do/code in your utility :)

Comment: @Shashi Did you try somethink ? If my answer was helpful please accept it as good answer. If you have some doubts make a more specific question :)